# React multiple components nested routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have created a multiple components in one .js file
For e.g: Under `Home.js` file --> blog, about and contact class components

[Home.js File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZOh3.png)

So now I want to render all the components(blog, about, contact) under home.
[App.js file where I want to route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dR37.png)

I am not sure what to add in `element` or any other options are there.

I tried with the `<Home />` but it's not the solution.

Comment: Please can you post your code here instead of pictures of your code

Comment: Please [edit] the post to include the code as properly formatted and readable code snippets instead of images. Images are less accessible, can be more difficult to read, and are not copy/pasteable. See [mcve].

Comment: @DrewReese
How can i achieve sub-child element in path by react routing concept?
For e.g:
Home
     Home 1
     Home 2
     Home 3
Blog
About
Contact
Here if i will click on Home 1 component, I am getting the data, but in the relative path, i want to get the ""Home" as well which i am not getting.
Basically I want to get 
localhost:3000/home/home1 
but I am getting localhost:3000/home1

Comment: @DrewReese
Used nested routing, but i am struggling with the path itself,

Comment: If I understand your additional question you want the `Home` component to render some additional descendent routes? It might be easier to understand if you made a new post for this new specific question, with a good [mcve] of the code so we can see what it's doing. If you create a post feel free to ping me here in a comment with a link to it and I can take a look when available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the `Home` component to remain mounted and also render the `Blog`, `About`, or `Contact` component as a [layout route](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#layout-routes) then `Home` should be updated to render an [`Outlet` component](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#outlets) for the nested routes to render their content into.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

export const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      This is home page
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
};

export const Blog = () => <div>Blog Content</div>;
export const About = () => <div>About Content</div>;
export const Contact = () => <div>Contact Details</div>;
```

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <HeaderP />
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />}>
      <Route path="blog" element={<Blog />} />
      <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
      <Route path="contact" element={<Contact />} />
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

If you just want each component rendered alone on its own page then unnest the blog, about, and contact routes.

```
export const Home = () => <div>This is home page</div>;
export const Blog = () => <div>Blog Content</div>;
export const About = () => <div>About Content</div>;
export const Contact = () => <div>Contact Details</div>;
```

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <HeaderP />
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/blog" element={<Blog />} />
    <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
    <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```